# Can I use substitutions to solve complex integrals?

Tags: complex-analysis

I was searching online if it was possible to perform a change of variable when computing complex integrals, and on one website they said that it could be done.

However, that would imply the following: Let $f$ be any complex function defined at least on the set $\{z\in \mathbb C:|z|=1\}$

Let $\gamma=e^{it},t\in[0,2\pi]$

Then: $$\int_\gamma f=i\int_0^{2\pi} f(e^{it})\cdot e^{it} dt$$

Let $u=e^{it}$. When $t=0, u=1$ and when $t=2\pi, u = 1$, so the integral becomes:

$$\int_1^1f(u)du = 0$$

This is obviously false. Does that mean that we can't perform substitutions when solving complex integrals? If not, how can we solve them without using Cauchy/Residue theorem? By separating the function into a real and complex part and integrating them separately?

Comment: [Integration by substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution) is about substitution functions $\phi:[a, b] \to I$ where $I \subset \Bbb R$ is an *interval.*

Comment: there is a path from 1 to 1 so the notation $\int_1^1$ doesn't make sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can perform *some* substitutions in complex integrals. However, anytime you make a substitution, instead, you are performing a mapping in the complex plane. So you are not only affecting the integrand but also the curve and every singularity the function has.

And if you do this, it's better mapping the original complex function first to a new complex plane (let's say, from $z$ to $w$) and then writing any parametrizarion you'd like to use.

I have some examples involving the *inversion mapping* $w=1/z$ like $\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{1}{\sin{(1/z)}} dz$ which resists the use of Integral formulas and residues theorem.

Answer (score 1):

The path of integration is a circle in the complex plane.  So note that this is really better thought of as a line integral.  Just as with a line integral you usually can't just replace it with a simple integral with end points.  You have to parameterize the curve.  There are many ways to integrate "with respect to" your complex variable, u, which begin and end at u = 1.  But you have to pay attention to the path you've followed between the start at u = 1 and the finish back at u = 1.